# How to call theme image in .html file

Tags: magento2, html

I want to call a image `<myvendor/mytheme>/web/images/image.png`

in

```
\Magento_Checkout\web\template\minicart\content.html
```

can anyone let me know how can i call image in `<img src=""/>` tag ?